# How to use Google Analytics in a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Analytics to track FireFox extension use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770373/google-analytics-to-track-firefox-extension-use)

I tried injecting a `script` tag on the page with analytics code, but it is reporting 200+ absolute unique visitors from me alone...

Is there a way to use the script that will provide me a more accurate result?

Comment: @Shaz I've looked in that but I just don't understand what that does. And how would that get more accurate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the cookies required to track a user aren't being registered properly and used by the ga.js script. Without a way to identify a visitor GA will think that every time you call the tracking code it comes from a new visitor.

You could try constructing the tracking pixel yourself and sending it to GA whenever you want to register a pageview. You would need to simulate the `__utm.gif` request and place your own values into the URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to track you may not need Google Analytics. Mozilla's addon.mozilla.org portal already provides comprehensive tracking and usage statistics for addons.

To check if Mozilla provides what you need go to the [Statistics Dashboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/statistics/) and choose the statistics for one of the publicly available addons.