# Google analytics - track event in firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics, firefox-addon

I develop a firefox extension and I want to track events in the extension using Google analytics.
I tried to add the extension and fire an event but it didn't work:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var _AnalyticsCode = 'UA-1234567-9';
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', _AnalyticsCode]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();


function googleAnalyticsTrackEvent(category, action) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action]);
}
googleAnalyticsTrackEvent('category','action');
```

**Is there any other way I could track events in my plugin?**

Comment: Where are you inserting this? Is it part of a chrome script or part of a content script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics to track FireFox extension use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770373/google-analytics-to-track-firefox-extension-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://code.google.com/p/google-analytics-js/
[Google Analytics to track FireFox extension use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770373/google-analytics-to-track-firefox-extension-use)